# IdentityConfig is missing in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am migrating my project to MVC 5 and I've just installed Visual Studio 2013 RC. As far as I can see there must be a file named *IdentityConfig.cs* in the *App_Start* directory, but even if I create a new project, that file is missing. I am thinking that maybe it could be about version of Visual Studio that I am using. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Also, I can't add Roles or Membership Providers to *web.config*. How can I do this with IdentityConfig?

Comment: Are you following the [migration guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)?

Comment: still working on migration but the thing is even i open a new empty project it is missing IdentityConfig.cs.

Comment: What makes you think the file should be there? Have you read that somewhere?

Comment: Yes. There was an article about while i was trying to use UserRole class (which wasn't running until i install WebMatrix).

Comment: you can see it from here: [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B314#fbid=CqWK93CGT6)

Comment: I don't have a 2013 available right now, perhaps someone else can confirm. Relevant part of the video starts at 53:25

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IdentityConfig.cs is no longer required and was removed in the RC version. This is discussed in the article "[Introducing ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx)".  Here is the relevant snippet from this article.

> Following are the notable changes from 1.0.0-alpha1 – 1.0.0-beta1
>
> - In these templates you no longer need IdentityConfig.cs
> - Lots of public APIs were changed for renames and refactoring of code.
> - Transactions support was added to the framework.

Comment: Looking at the official NuGet ASP.NET Identity samples, they are using the *IdentityConfig* file for things like DatabaseInitializers, registration of other authentication providers (e.g., Two Factor, Facebook, etc.) as well as defining their own ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationRoleManager, etc.  So, without this file now, I wonder then what is the "best practice" or general convention for where people are putting these things now?

Comment: @Funka - Good observation. The ASP.NET Identity team has reintroduced IdentityConfig.cs in the version 2.x samples.  It is still not required but what this team chose to throw a lot of stuff in for the sample to work.  Best practice? At first blush it does not seem so, but I would have to review it in more detail to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you should find in App_Start is a Startup.Auth.cs file configuring the authentication / authorization middleware for the site.

ASP.NET MVC 5 doesn't use the role providers and membership providers that have been around since ASP.NET 2.0. You could still configure those into a web site, but then you'd probably want to get rid of the middleware.

By middleware, I mean most of the authz features are moving into OWIN middleware for ASP.NET. The StartupAuth.cs file and the AccountController in a new MVC 5 project show you a bit how everything can work together, although it is not well documented.